# Python : Search patterns from file1 in a list of files

Tags: python, regex

I have a file which contains all the list of patterns. The patterns are of this format (high:low). high and low separated by a colon.

Sample patterns in file1:

> -6447867851221037056:-3788579599719006014
>
> -6449238495544274944:-3932696454242172736
>
> -6449265231715692544:-4004752252983770939
>
> -6449203349826891776:-2995947018784538426
>
> -6447968581089030144:-3659104829784325951
>
> -6449244980944891904:-1059398397250633536
>
> -6449247532155465728:-1915082300761767744
>
> -6447984223359922176:-4220924871888797497

Now, I have a list of files in a search directory. I want to search the patterns from the above file in all the files in the search directory which matches file `*`yyyy-mm-dd-hh`*` pattern.

eg:

Search all the patterns from file1 in search directory with filename pattern `*`2015-09-07-06`*`

> search_file.2015-09-07-05-45
>
> search_file.2015-09-07-06-47
>
> search_file.2015-09-07-06-48
>
> search_file.2015-09-07-06-50
>
> search_file.2015-09-07-06-52

I know how to do this in bash (grep -f file1 `*`2015-09-07-06`*`). But I'm new to python and have very little clue of how to proceed further. Any kind of pointers is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this package: https://amoffat.github.io/sh/

It will enable you to run your shell command in python easily.

You can use pip to install it.

Answer (score 0):

The efficient and easy way is with shell commands. Hope you will be knowing os.system for execute shell commands in python. I have tried the same logic in python.

```
    import glob
    file_list = glob.glob("*2015-09-07-06*")

    input_filename = "file1.txt"
    with open(input_filename,'r') as input:
        input_data = input.readlines()

    for each_file in file_list:
        open_file = open(each_file,'r')
        file_data = open_file.readlines()
        identified = set(input_data) & set(file_data)
        if identified:
            print "filename : " + str(each_file)+" : "+str(identified)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
def searchpattern():
    with open("file1.txt", 'r') as fobj:
        f = fobj.readlines()
        pattern = '2015-09-07-06'

        for i in f:
            m = re.search(pattern, i)
            if m:
                print(i)
            else:
                pass
if __name__ == '__main__':
    searchpattern()
```

Output:

```
2015-09-07-06-45
2015-09-07-06-46
```